# Dynamically set button width and height

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am new to Windows app developemnt:

I have a scenario where i need to display matrix of button with text below that, i am able to do that but the issue here is the matrix can be of any thing 2x2,2x3,2x4 or 2x6.

but the button should be square and not rectangle, if i add image to it then the image looks stretched.

here is my code :

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        int numberOfColumns = 2;
        int numberOfRows = 3;
        public double cellWidth;
        public double cellHeight;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(SetGridCellWidthAndHeight);

        }

       void SetGridCellWidthAndHeight(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cellWidth = GridWindows.ActualHeight / numberOfColumns;
            cellHeight = GridWindows.ActualHeight / numberOfRows;
            this.GridWindows.Children.Add(SetUpGridLayout());
        }

        private Grid SetUpGridLayout()
        {
            Grid grid = new Grid();
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

            // Create column and row definitions.
            ColumnDefinition[] columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition[numberOfColumns];
            RowDefinition[]  rowDefinition = new RowDefinition [numberOfRows];

            for (int i = 0; i < columnDefinition.Count(); i++)
            {
                columnDefinition[i] = new ColumnDefinition();
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < rowDefinition.Count(); i++)
            {
                rowDefinition[i] = new RowDefinition();
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition[i]);
            }

            int count = 1;

                for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++)
                    {
                        StackPanel gridViewStackPlanel = new StackPanel();
                        gridViewStackPlanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

                        Button button = new Button();
                        button.Width = cellWidth*0.8;
                        button.Height = cellHeight *0.8;
                        //topicButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                        button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                         button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                        //To display the Topic name
                        TextBlock name= new TextBlock();
                        name.Text = " Value" + count;
                        name.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        name.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

                        gridViewStackPlanel.Children.Add(button);
                        gridViewStackPlanel.Children.Add(name);

                        count++;

                        grid.Children.Add(gridViewStackPlanel);
                        Grid.SetColumn(gridViewStackPlanel, column);
                        Grid.SetRow(gridViewStackPlanel, row);
                    }
                }
          return grid;

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

When you write a code like this:

```
button.Width = cellWidth * 0.8;
button.Height = cellHeight * 0.8;
```

You would get a square only if `cellWidth == cellHeight`. And that is most likely not true. So your widths and heights are different. Consider replacing the above with something like this:

```
cellWidth = Math.Min(GridWindows.ActualHeight / numberOfColumns, GridWindows.ActualHeight / numberOfRows);

button.Width = cellWidth * 0.8;
button.Height = cellWidth * 0.8;
```

Now it will be square.